# How to rename files using Windows command prompt with keeping first 6 characters and replace all others by fixed text?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have a batch of PDF files in a folder and I am trying to rename them.

Example:

```
File1_20170501_data.pdf
File2_20170401_statistics.pdf
Sale2_20170404_Misc.pdf
```

I only want to keep the first six characters of each file name (the five characters left to underscore and the underscore) and replace everything behind with `sample data`.

The final file names should be:

```
File1_sample data.pdf
File2_sample data.pdf
Sale2_sample data.pdf
```

Anyone can advice which command line to use for this file renaming task?

Comment: What have you tried so far, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50177422/edit) your question to show us your code even if not working.

Comment: What if there arise collisions? for example, if there are two files `File1_foo.pdf` and `File1_bar.pdf`?

Answer (score 3):

Given your provided information at the time of this answer, one simple command should do what you need:

```dos
Ren "C:\path to\a folder\?????_*.pdf" "?????_sample data.pdf"
```